# Calendar popup missing some of the CSS styles

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, calendar

The calendar popup in the [Profile tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=profile) under the **Visited** section, missing some of the CSS styles.

**Current Calendar UI:**

[image: Current UI]

**Old Calendar UI:**

[image: Old UI]

Comment: What specifically are you referring to? The gray header, the italic month names, and the table borders?

Comment: The changes seem deliberate. For example, the previously gray header currently has `.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-header { background: none; }` in `primary.css`. This doesn’t seem accidental.

Comment: I actually prefer the new style.  Also, that's a *very* small bug, one I personally wouldn't bother spending dev time on.